# nested terms aggregation on object containing a string field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I like to run a nested terms aggregation on string field which is inside an object.

Usually, I use this query

```
      "terms": {
        "field": "fieldname.keyword"
      }
```

to enable fielddata

But I am unable to do that for a nested document like this

```
{
      "nested": {
        "path": "objectField"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "allmyaggs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "objectField.fieldName.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The above query is just returning an empty buckets array

Is there a way this can be done without enabling field-data by default during index mapping.
Since that will take a large heap memory and I have already loaded a huge data without it

document mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "productname": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "productlineseqno": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "invoiceitemname": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "productlinename": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "productlinedescription": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "isprescribable": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "iscontrolleddrug": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
```

sample document

```
{
  "productname": [
    {
      "productlineseqno": "1.58",
      "iscontrolleddrug": "false",
      "productlinename": "Consultations",
      "productlinedescription": "Consultations",
      "isprescribable": "false",
      "invoiceitemname": "invoice name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Fixed

By changing the mapping to enable field data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested query is used to access nested fields similarly [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) is needed to aggregation on nested fields

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "fieldname": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "objectField"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "fields": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "objectField.fieldname.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT1:

If you are searching for productname.invoiceitemname.keyword  then it will give empty bucket as no field exists with that name.

You need to define  your mapping like below

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "productname": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "productlineseqno": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "invoiceitemname": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields":{       --> note
              "keyword":{
                "type":"keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "productlinename": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "productlinedescription": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "isprescribable": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "iscontrolleddrug": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html)

> It is often useful to index the same field in different ways for
>   different purposes. This is the purpose of multi-fields. For instance,
>   a string field could be mapped as a text field for full-text search,
>   and as a keyword field for sorting or aggregations:

When mapping is not explicitly provided, keyword fields are created by default. If you are creating your own mapping(which you need to do for nested type), you need to provide keyword fields in mapping, wherever you intend to use them

Comment: This did not work. let me edit my question to show the full query

Comment: @gdvigneshwar, it works for me. Can you add your mapping and a sample document in question

Comment: thanks for your reply. Have added mapping and sample doc